# Reload Div on button Click with .load();

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have an OWL carousel (v2) that when you click the next button it reloads a div that contains an Ad (div is called .slideAd) -- i have looked at other pages on SO and none seem to work -- i feel like i have it, what am i missing?

I have this code, but it always throws a 500 server error, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$(".rSlidesNav .n").click(function(e) {
    var pathtopage = window.location.href;
            $('.slideAd').load(pathtopage + ' #slideAd');   
});
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to reload only a single div out of an HTML page over the network.

Comment: **#slideAd** or **.slideAd** anyway I agree with @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick reload the div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413200/onclick-reload-the-div-only)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.get()` , `.outerHTML`

```
  // `""` as `url` should request current document
  $.get("", function(html) {
    $(".slideAd").html($(html).find("#slideAd")[0].outerHTML)
  })
```

Comment: Hi, still getting that internal server error with this code. any other thoughts, or can it just not be done?

Comment: Is `php` serving `html` ? `500` is server side error code

Comment: yeah im getting this error in console - send
m.extend.ajax
 m.(anonymous function) 
m.event.dispatch
 r.handle